# How Do I Make This Print?

Tags: c

I understand how to print the stuff now: I forgot to allocate memory for the array. However, now I can't seem to get the math right in the final result.

Prompt:

> A boy goes to buy video games from a shop. The shop contains N unique
> video games. The prices of the games are given in the form of an array
> A. The price of ith games is A[i]. Now the boy has q queries, in each
> query he wants to know the number of unique games that have a price
> less than the given amount M. Input:
>
> The first line contains an integer N total number of unique video
> games available in the shop.
>
> The second line contains N space-separated integers (the price of the
> games).
>
> The third line contains Q number of queries.
>
> Each of the next Q lines contains integer M. Output:
>
> For each query output number of games having price less than M for
> that query. Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 5
> 1 4 10 5 6
> 4
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 11
> ```
>
> Output for the sample input:
>
> ```
> 1
> 1
> 2
> 5
> ```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
int *Prices, UniqueGames, j, h, i, numPrice, numQueries, *PriceQueries, *TestResults;

    //Making Arrays
    printf("Enter number of unique games.");
    scanf("%d", &UniqueGames); // Array Size

    Prices = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*UniqueGames); // Memory Allocation

    for(j = 0; j < UniqueGames; j++){ // Filling Array
        scanf("%d", &h);
        *(Prices+j) = h;
    }

    printf("Enter number of queries.");
    scanf("%d", &numQueries); // Array Size

    PriceQueries = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numQueries); // Memory Allocation

    for(j = 0; j < numQueries; j++){ // Filling Array
        scanf("%d", &h);
        *(PriceQueries+j) = h;
    }

    //Calculations
    TestResults = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numQueries);
    h = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < numQueries; j++){ // Filling array TestResults with test results
        for (i = 0; i < UniqueGames; i++) {
            if (Prices[i] < PriceQueries[i]) {
                h = h + 1;
                TestResults[j] = h;
        }
            else {
                h = 0;
            }

        }
        printf("%d\n", TestResults[j]);

    }

    free(Prices);
    free(PriceQueries);
    free(TestResults);
   return 0;
}
```

I'm filling an array of prices for each game and an array of prices for the number of queries the user inputs. I fill an array of test results based on the prices within the query set and I'm trying to print that final array.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You have `*(TestResults + j) = h;` and then immediately overwrite the value with `TestResults[j] = TestResults[j+1];` (which in any case hasn't yet been initialised). Note that `*(TestResults + j)` and `TestResults[j]` are effectively the same.

Comment: There's no need to put the results in an array. You can just print each result after you calculate it, without saving it anywhere.

Comment: @SupportUkraine only one more 'close' vote is needed to have denied OP any help at all. I know they can edit it and hope for it to be reopened but... Your other point, is that the ones I am really tired of are the problem dumps that show zero effort, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: @SupportUkraine perhaps they will be back in an hour, not realising the reaction time to questions. I added more to the previous comment.

Comment: @SupportUkraine voting to re-open.

Comment: @WeatherVane Requirements have to be included as text as well.

Comment: @user229044 done, I see.

Comment: @SupportUkraine "Would you sign up and ask your very first question and just walk away for the next hours?" I wouldn't, but that seems to happen most of the time here, OP disappears never to be seen again after asking. This is a rare case of sticking around and editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'calculations' are needless complex making it difficult to understand. (And the wonky indentation does not help.)

```
//Calculations
TestResults = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numQueries); // <== uninitialised array
h = 0;
for(j = 0; j < numQueries; j++){ // Filling array TestResults with test results
    for (i = 0; i < UniqueGames; i++) {
        if (Prices[i] < PriceQueries[i]) { // <= one index should be 'j'
            h = h + 1;
            TestResults[j] = h; // <== assignment should be accumulation
    }
        else {
            h = 0; // <== why reset???
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n", TestResults[j]); // <== why use an array???

}
```

Rewriting (with comments) may help clarify what you seem to want to achieve

```
//Calculations
for( j = 0; j < numQueries; j++ ) { // for each query amount...
    int cnt = 0; // count the games...
    for( i = 0; i < UniqueGames; i++ ) // for each game
        if( Prices[ i ] < PriceQueries[ j ] ) // priced less than this query amount
            cnt++;

    printf( "Query %d: %d games cost less than %d\n", j, cnt, PriceQueries[ j ] );
}
```

Comment: Nod for the technical categorization of the indentation problem alone... `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin C code blocks should be hung in art galleries... Some for their sheer elegance and beauty; some for their Salvador Dali-like surreal presentation... `:-)`

Comment: K&R `1TBS` is the only way to fly (your mileage and taste may vary) Allman is a close 2nd [Indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) CodeBlocks - Picasso Impressionistic Indentation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "Well written code is self documenting" (however one wears one's braces...) `:-)`